# Confusion with more

Tags: comparative-constructions

Read the following sentences.

> He has more useful information.

The sentence meant that the information was more useful.
If I want to tell the information is more, what do I say?
I think

> I have more information that is useful.

Comment: As pointed out, your first phrasing is ambiguous. But *He has **additional** useful information* isn't.

Comment: Then , is the following unambiguous

Comment: He has more vintage cars
.But
 I do find these ambiguous

Comment: I've never encountered "more vintage" being used with the sense "older" (more obviously falling into the category "vintage cars"). As with, say, "classic", adjectival "vintage" isn't "gradable", so there's no scope for ambiguity there.

Answer (score 2):

The statement is ambiguous.

**More** can be understood to modify both **information** and **useful**.

So the statement can mean either that:

1. He has more information that is useful

or

2. He has information that is more useful.

To make the meaning clear, you have to choose between them.

Comment: How do I remove the ambiguity then

Comment: You rewrite it in one of the two ways I have illustrated, depending on what you intend.